# Import export in microsoft sql server 2008R2

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

i am using Microsoft SQL server2008R2. i have created database in the SQL server. now i want to export data tables in different form like CSV or text for creating ETL in Business Intelligence Component.

Comment: nothing is on screen :(

Comment: There are many ways to do this. You can use BCP Utility, Powershell, SSIS just to name a few. I prefer powershell as the BCP utility has some limitations.